# How to render a message in H1 element using geolocation function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, geolocation

In this code I would like to show a message in the **h1** element in case the browser doesn't support geolocation or the user doesn't allow to check its current location. After this part of code it continues, and if geolocation is enabled, I fetch the information and render it.

```
function getLocation() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    const errorGettingGeolocation = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser or was not allowed by user.";
    const cityHtml = document.getElementById("cityName");
    cityHtml.innerText = errorGettingGeolocation;
    return;
  } else if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
}
```

How can i render this message and then continue running the code?
EDIT:
When I console.log inside function getLocation, I get return, but if I console.log inside if (!navigator.geolocation), I don't get any return. It never check this if condition.

Comment: `innerText` accepts "rendered" html. try `cityHtml.innerHTML = errorGettingGeolocation ` instead. (keep uppercasing like that. )

Comment: I tried it but still not working. When I console.log inside function getLocation, I get return, but if I console.log in if (!navigator.geolocation), I don't get return. It never check this if condition.